# I want to change one item(color & icon) in menu navigation bar or add text (New with red color)

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I want to change text and icon color of navigation drawable and add new Word with diffrent color
Can this is posible ?
I am using android navigationview with navigation drawable i can change text with this

```
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(" Invite Friends New");
    spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.kart)), 0, spannableString.length(), 0);
     navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.invite_friends)
   .setTitle(spannableString);
```

I want that Invite friends in black color and new word is in red color is this possible ?
& how to change icon color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's posseble just u need to add html code like

```
    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(Html.fromHtml("<font color=#090a0a>Invite Friends </font><font color=#e00a02>New</font>");
spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.kart)), 0, spannableString.length(), 0);
 navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.invite_friends)
.setTitle(spannableString);
```

hope will help you that .

Comment: SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(Html.fromHtml("<font color=#090a0a>Invite Friends </font><font color=#f9a506>      New</font>"));
        navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.invite_friends).setTitle(spannableString);
this works change colors only

Comment: you are wellcome :)